# Difference between vertices and edges [Graphs, Algorithm and DS]

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

I've just now started reading an Algorithms book that defined Graphs as follows:

> Graphs – which represent relationships
>   between arbitrary pairs of objects.
>   Figure 1.8(b) models a network of
>   roads as a graph, where the vertices
>   are cities and the edges are roads
>   connecting pairs of cities. Graphs are
>   likely the object in question whenever
>   you seek a “network,” “circuit,”
>   “web,” or “relationship.”

Figure 1.8(b) is this:
[image]

What confuses me here is the following line:

> ... where the vertices are cities and the
>   edges are roads connecting pairs of
>   cities ...

Comment: -1 I'm sorry but a simple plain old dictionary would have answered your question. I have no idea why anyone would upvote this question. Even worse the accepted answer, 12 upvotes? Something is really wrong here.

Comment: @DaClown: I asked the same question with some of the other non-native English speakers just now, and all of them had the same notion as mine. Now it looks obvious to me, too. But when I asked the question then, it wasn't. I did search the dictionary, and searched Google with same title as this question; I didn't find any assuring answer. That's why I posted it here. An example helps sometimes than a plain dictionary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vertices are the dots, edges are the lines. Hence cities and roads.

I'm not sure what confuses you, but in general graphs are indeed used to model connections between objects.

If you have a bunch of objects (vertices) that may be "connected" to one another, a Graph would be the high level data structure to maintain it. I'm saying "high level" because in practice you will probably need supporting data structures to maintain a graph in memory/database/file: matrices, lists of links, many-to-many tables etc.

If the "direction" is not important, like in the case of the plot above (i.e. all roads are bidirectional), you have an "undirected graph". If the connection direction does have an importance (for example if there are unidirectional roads between cities), you'll have a "directed graph", where every edge is actually an "arrow", pointing at a certain direction.

If you're very new to this, I recommend reading the relevant [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). For some "real" studying, I recommend [Cormen et al's Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937), the book I studied from, which is in my opinion one of the best computer science books ever written.

Comment: Rax, thanks for that explanation! English is not my native; I get confused sometimes because of the wrong notions and meanings I carried ever since I started learning. I was under the impression that an edge is the point of intersection of two lines, and vertices are the lines.

Answer (score 5):

Vertices are the nodes of the graph.
Edges are the arcs that connect pairs of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

if u count every line u see,thats the vertices.edges are the corners[eg-a sphere has no corners and no vertices but has i face.if u wanna know about all the properties of 3D shapes search 3D shapes on your computer.u will get more explanation.